# When does memory get allocated for HashMap elements?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to initialize a HashMap with 500 elements, all set to zeroes. I tried using Lambda forEach loop but the size of the map is still zero even after completion of the lambda loop. 
I was curious to know when the memory gets allocated for put operation.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(500);

map.keySet().forEach(i -> map.put(i, new Integer(0)));

System.out.println("Size of the HashMap using Lambda forEach loop: " + map.size());

for (int i=0; i < 500; i ++){
    map.put(i,0);
}

System.out.println("Size of the HashMap using regular for loop: " + map.size());
```

Output:

```
Size of the HashMap using Lambda forEach loop: 0
Size of the HashMap using regular for loop: 500
```

PS: I understand there is another method using Java8 streams for adding elements to hashmap but I am more interested in knowing the put operation.

Comment: You're iterating over the keys of the map, but you haven't put anything in the map yet. So the keySet is empty. What's surprising?

Comment: If the map wasn’t empty, calling `put` while iterating over it must be considered broken. Besides, what’s the point of `new Integer(0)`?

Comment: Note the keys in a HashMap<Integer,anything> can be any integers not just 0..N-1; for example they could perfectly well be 1000100 1000503 1001002 1001501 etc. If your keys are always 0..N-1 you can use a (builtin) array or an ArrayList for better efficiency than a HashMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(500);
```

creates an empty Map with an initial capacity of 500.

Therefore `map.keySet()` returns an empty `Set` and the `forEach` call does nothing.

> I was curious to know when the memory gets allocated for put operation

Whenever you put a new key in the `Map` (i.e. a key that wasn't already in the `Map`), a new `Map.Entry` instance is created. That's when the memory is allocated.

Instantiating the `HashMap` with a given capacity only allocates the memory for the initial array that will hold the `Map`'s entries (and even that is not necessarily true, since the allocation of the array can be lazy).

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation.